# Is there any research relating to reform and corruption in local and small scale authorities?

Tags: united-kingdom, local-government, corruption

I am looking for solid evidence led input on the topic of reforming and reducing corruption (or the appearance thereof) in local authorities. Ideally this would be based in the UK as this is where the information will be used.

Do such studies exist?

Comment: There are such studies, but obviously you really want to know where they can be found which is a much harder question to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well you could start with the magazine *Private Eye* who run a regular column on "[Rotten Boroughs](http://www.private-eye.co.uk/rotten-boroughs)". Other organisations attempt to trace [Local authority corruption](https://www.rottencouncil.co.uk/council-corruption/).

If you are looking for a more general survey you could read the report on [Mounting Risks](http://www.transparency.org.uk/publications/corruption-in-uk-local-government-the-mounting-risks/) of corruption by transparency international.

Or if you are looking for the government policy there is the [Local governemnt counter fraud and corruption strategy 2016-2019](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/503657/Fighting_fraud_and_corruption_locally_strategy.pdf)

Roughly to sumarise these documents: Corruption is a problem, and a growing problem. However it is currently mostly small scale. The government is aware and does have a strategy in place.

Comment: Depending on the time scale involved, I think it is very hard to say that it is not a shrinking problem. For example, the UK ca. 1700 CE was much more corrupt than it is today.